# Query Redshift from NodeJS Express app (@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a simple Express app and I am trying to figure out how to get data from AWS Redshift using the "@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data" module.

Following the example code from the module's GitHub page, I'm doing this:

```
const {
  RedshiftDataClient,
  ListSchemasCommand,
} = require("@aws-sdk/client-redshift-data");

const client = new RedshiftDataClient({ region: "eu-central-1" });

  console.log(`RedshiftDataClient created :::: ${JSON.stringify(client)}`);

  const params = {
    /** input parameters */
  };
  const command = new ListSchemasCommand(params);

  try {
    const data = await client.listSchemas(command);
    // process data.
    console.log(`PROCESSING DATA :::: ${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  } catch (error) {
    // error handling.
    console.log(`LIST SCHEMAS ERROR :::: ${error}`);
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-redshift-data

I'm getting an error saying:

```
TypeError: client.listSchemas is not a function
```

It looks like the RedshiftDataClient that I created via the constructor isn't in the expected format. This is what I get when I log it:

```
{
  "middlewareStack": {},
  "config": {
    "apiVersion": "2019-12-20",
    "disableHostPrefix": false,
    "extensions": [],
    "httpAuthSchemes": [
      {
        "schemeId": "aws.auth#sigv4",
        "signer": {}
      }
    ],
    "logger": {},
    "serviceId": "Redshift Data",
    "runtime": "node",
    "requestHandler": {
      "metadata": {
        "handlerProtocol": "http/1.1"
      },
      "configProvider": {}
    },
    "defaultSigningName": "redshift-data",
    "tls": true,
    "isCustomEndpoint": false,
    "systemClockOffset": 0,
    "signingEscapePath": true
  }
}
```

It doesn't have 'listSchemas' or any other methods.

What could I be missing here? Thanks

Comment: How are you importing the client?

Comment: @Corey - updated code sample with import statement, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between `RedshiftDataClient` and `RedshiftData`. It looks like you're combining syntax from both.

You either want:

```
const client = new RedshiftDataClient({});
client.send(new ListSchemasCommand({}))
```

or

```
const client = new RedshiftData({});
client.listSchemas({})
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/introduction/

Comment: You're right - thanks. It seems I combined syntax from both the v3 and v2-compatible examples here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/clients/client-redshift-data